Basement framing over dimple mat and french drain
I bought a home with an unfinished basement with the intent to finish it. I live in the Pacific Northwest of the US where we get lots of rain, and there was some water intrusion. We re-graded the land outside to slope more away from the house and hired a professional to install a french drain around the perimeter walls that goes into a sump pump. They also installed a dimple mat that goes about 48 inches up the wall all around the perimeter.
Through two rain seasons, we've had no water intrusion and I'm ready to finish the basement.
My question is about where I should frame the walls and how I should insulate--I've read that I should put up a 1/2" rigid foam board all along my perimeter walls behind the framing, but I'm not sure how to do so with the dimple mat. Can I adhere the foam board to the dimple mat? Can I frame right up against the foam once it's installed, or does there need to be a gap?


Is the dimple mat tied into the French drain? You usually put dimple mats on the exterior of the foundation.

yeah, the dimple mat ties into the french drain. it's been effective for keeping water out of the basement but now i don't the best way to frame in front of it and install 1/2" foam board.

Are your walls poured concrete?  Where does the dimple mat drain to at the bottom?

the dimple mat is tucked into the concrete and ties into the french drain

The best way is to build the stud walls in sections. Apply the ridgid insulation to the back of the walls, lift it up and slide the walls in place leaving a gap between the face of the insulation and the dimple mats of about an inch. Anchor the sections to each other and into the floor and overhead joists. You can then install your electrics, fill the wall with insulation if desired, cover with a vapor barrier and then drywall.

Don't the dimple mat and rigid foam both serve as vapor barriers?   Why is a third one needed?

The dimple mat is a water barrier. The pictures show it does not reach the underside of the joists and so cannot control for vapor. The rigid foam could be a vapor barrier but there is no way to fully seal the foam with the above construction method and integrate it into the remaining building envelope. I consider the rigid board to be a thermal break to improve the overall performance of the interior wall.
